# Using find_by_sql to replicate includes & joins behaviour (single query to build associations)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

We have a rather simple query that works perfectly with AR query constructs:

```
user = User.includes({:network => :product}).joins({:network => :product}).where(:id => user_id).first
```

This executes a single query on the database, populating the eagerly loaded collections (ie: I can call `user.product.network.name` without invoking an additional query to the DB).

We want to add some "pseudo" columns to the `User` object that don't exist in the User's table, but we want to populate as part of this initial query.  The SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    "users".*,
    "networks".*,
    "products".*, 
    (select count("spaces".id) from spaces "spaces" where "spaces".owner_id = "users".id) as spaces_count
FROM
    users "users" 
JOIN
    networks "networks" 
    on "networks".id = "users".network_id 
JOIN products "products" 
    on "products".id="networks".product_id 
WHERE "users".id=?
```

The addition of the "spaces_count" column with the (un-optimized) inner query is the only "pseduo" column at this stage, but the view is to add more.

In the `User` class (an ActiveRecord model) has in it:

```
attr_accessible :spaces_count
```

In order to execute the SQL query we're using the following:

```
user = find_by_sql(sql)
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new([user], {:network => :product}).run
```

Where sql is the query included above.

The result is a `User` model, populated, as expected, including the `spaces_count` "pseudo" column, however as part of calling `run` on the associations preloader, it hits the DB two more times:

```
1.9.3p125 :465 > ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new([user], {:network => :product}).run
  Network Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "networks".* FROM "networks" WHERE "networks"."id" IN (1)
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" IN (1)
=> [{:network=>:product}]
```

Is there a way to use `ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader` to eagerly fetch the associations, without hitting the DB additional times, as per the way `includes` with `joins` does it?

We're using Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.9.3-p125 and PG 9.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way to do exactly what you ask, I do know you don't have to - just use more of those AR 'query constructs'.

First of all, you can specify a custom select:

```
users = User.includes({:network => :project}).select('users.*, (select count("spaces".id) from spaces "spaces" where "spaces".owner_id = "users".id) as spaces_count').joins({:network => :product}).where(:id => user_id).first
```

You can tack these on in any order - my personal convention is that 'includes' comes first, then everything else in the order it appears in the query, but that's just me. This will still get the eager loading you need, and you can get the value of the 'pseudo-columns' by calling their names on the returned objects:

```
users.first.spaces_count
```

N.B. The PostgreSQL adapter seems to return these values as strings, no matter what their actual type in the database, so you may need to convert them afterward:

```
users.first.spaces_count.to_i
```

As a final note, while I do hope this solution works for you, I would also be interested in an answer about the method you suggest - customized eager loading via AR::Associations::Preloader sounds both cool and useful.